# Signature operations may leak the private key; signature verification should be safe?

Tags: public-key, dsa

What does this warning mean:

> Signature operations may leak the private key. Signature verification should be safe.

A haskell cryto library displays the quoted warning above (see [Crypto.PubKey.ECC.ECDSA](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.21/docs/Crypto-PubKey-ECC-ECDSA.html)) but I don't really grasp **why** they are producing that warning.

Can you please explain what this means (from a cryptographical point of view)?

Comment: Well, signing does involve the private key wheras verification does not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors of the code also wrote:

> WARNING: Vulnerable to timing attacks.

They know their code can [leak information thru timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) of its operation. Therefore, they rightly wrote:

> Signature operations may leak the private key.
>   Signature verification should be safe.

The first sentence is because, due to the aforementioned information leak, the confidentiality of the private key (which must be used to perform a signature, and should be kept secret) could be compromised during a signature generation operation.

The second sentence is because, in a signature verification, the public key is used, and that is not secret. Thus, information leak is much less of an issue, and can't compromise the confidentiality of a key. However, there are rare situations where the signature itself is deemed secret (say, because it can be reused); that might explain the use of "should".